# Removing changing pattern from filenames in directory in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory containing files following the following naming convention:

```
Label_0000_AA.gz
Label_0001_BB.gz
Label_0002_CC.gz
...
```

All I want to do is to rename these files so that the _#### number pattern is removed, resulting in:

```
Label_AA.gz
Label_BB.gz
Label_CC.gz
...
```

but only up to a certain number. E.g.: I may have 10000 files but might only want to remove the pattern in the first 3000. Would this be possible using something like bash?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `prename` or `rename` -
(assuming the names are consistent)

```
for f in Label_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[A-Z][A-Z].gz
do mv "$f" "${f//_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/}"
done
```

To just do a certain range -

```
for n in {0000..2999}
do  for f in Label_${n}_??.gz
    do  mv $f ${f//_$n/}
    done
done
```

You're sure there are not collisions?

Answer (score 0):

If you can name the pattern you want to change/remove in a regex you can use the command `prename`:

```
prename 's/_[0-3][[:digit:]]{3}_/_/g' Label_*.gz
```

This regex would only remove numbers 0000-3999.

Using the flag `-n` does a "dry-run" and shows what it would do.

Edit: Thanks @KamilCuk to remind me about two `rename`s. I made it clear and changed the name to `prename`.

Comment: I'll give this a go, thanks! Say I want to remove up to exactly 0399, would the following syntax work?  ```rename 's/_[0][0-3][[:digit:]]{2}_/_/g' Label_*.gz```

Comment: Note thare are two `rename`s - [util linux rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) and [perl rename](http://man.he.net/man1/rename).

Comment: And I have none of those on my git bash emulation.